# System.ArgumentException when locking

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

In my real application I need to iterate collection, but it can be changed from other thread. So I need to copy collection to iterate on it. I reproduced this problem to small example, but apparently my lack of understanding of locks and threads results in `System.ArgumentException`. Tried different things with lock, but result is the same.

```
class Program
{
    static List<int> list;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
            if (i == 1000)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
                t.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    static void WorkThreadFunction()
    {
        lock (list)
        {
            List<int> tmp = list.ToList();  //Exception here!
            Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the message of that exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried Joel's suggestions. ConcurrentBag was very slow. Locking at each of millions iteration seems inefficient. Looks like Event Wait Handles are good in this case (takes 3 time less than with locks on my pc).

```
 class Program
{
    static List<int> list;
    static ManualResetEventSlim mres = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);

            if (i == 1000)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
                t.Start();
                mres.Wait();
            }
        }
    }

    static void WorkThreadFunction()
    {
        List<int> tmp = list.ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
        mres.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add that `Wait()` and `Set()` will cause your main thread to be blocked while your `WorkThreadFunction()` is running. You will always see your `list.Count` to be 1001 (until `Set()` is called) as your thread are now synchronized. This means that no adding operation on list will be done until `WorkThreadFunction` is completed.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
class Program
{
    static List<int> list;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            lock (list) //Lock before modification
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }
            if (i == 1000)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
                t.Start();
            }

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void WorkThreadFunction()
    {
        lock (list)
        {
            List<int> tmp = list.ToList();  //Exception here!
            Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens here is that your `list` is being modified while being converted to another list collection (where argument exception is happening). So to avoid that you will need to lock the list as shown above.

**Option 2: (No `lock`)**

Using Concurrent collections to remove the `lock`:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

//Change this line
static List<int> list;
//To this line
static ConcurrentBag<int> list;
```

And remove all `lock` statements.

Comment: Works, but this slows down execution of program almost 5 times. How can we block list only when we need to copy it, but not million times on each add operation?

Comment: Have you tried using the thread-safe  collections from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx you can use `ConcurrentBag<int>` and remove the `lock`. You can compare how the execution performance is.

Comment: With ConcurrentBag<int> it takes even 17 times longer than with no locks, and 3 time longer than with locks :(

Comment: @Dork, are you still locking something with `ConcurrentCollection`? Such performance loss isn't usual.

Comment: @VMAtm no. Removed all locked statements and changed List<int> to ConcurrentBag<int>

Answer (score 1):

I see some issues in your algorithm, and may be you should refactor it. In case of using either `locks` or `ConcurrentBag` class you should realize that the copying entire collection into new one simply for enumeration is very huge and very time-consuming operation, and during it you can't operate with collection efficiently.

```
lock (list)
{
    // VERY LONG OPERATION HERE
    List<int> tmp = list.ToList();  //Exception here!
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
}
```

You really shouldn't `lock` collection for such amount of time - at the end of the `for` loop you have a lot of `Threads` which are blocking each other. You have to use the [`TPL` classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for this approach and shouldn't use `Threads` directly.

The other case you can choose is to implement some of [optimistic lock-free algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz.aspx) with double check for the collection version, or even [lock-free and wait-free algorithm](http://www.drdobbs.com/lock-free-data-structures/184401865) with storing the snapshot of the collection and checking for it inside your methods for the collection access. [Additional information can be found here](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/writing-lock-free-code-a-corrected-queue/210604448).

I think that the information you gave isn't enough to suggest you the right way to solve your issue.

Comment: Actually my real program need to query collection rarely, so it wouldn't be big overhead, but thanks for links, found out lot of things.

Comment: If so, you definitely have to define your algorithm properly, may be with iteration over parts of collection.

Comment: Perfect. I can take Count of collection at the moment and iterate it using for loop. (not a problem in my case if element would be added while reading).  int n = list.Count.   list.Take(n) throws same exception, so I would need to use for loop instead of LINQ, but it's ok.